# grepl filter in R program

Tags: r, grepl

Trying to filter the rows which contains only the word DEV
but the below is pulling wrong matches like SEV HEV and BEV as well

Data

```
Airport_ID<-c("3001","3002","3003","3004")
    Airport_Name<-c("Adelaide DEV DTSUpdated","Brisbane HEV Land Airport Land ADTS",
                    "Washington SEV INC Airport DTSUpdated","DALLAS Airport BEV INCUpdated")
dfu<-data.frame(Airport_ID,Airport_Name)
```

Filter Code

```
Filter_Data <- dfu %>%  
                   dplyr::filter(grepl(" \\DEV\\ ",Airport_Name))
```

Intended Output:

```
    3001 Adelaide DEV DTSUpdated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
library(dplyr)

dfu |> filter(grepl("DEV" , Airport_Name , fixed = T))
```

- output

```
  Airport_ID            Airport_Name
1       3001 Adelaide DEV DTSUpdated
```